# Count number of cells in a column with conditional formatting from VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I've done some searching and I can't find anything that seems to match up with what I'm trying to do precisely. I'm familiar with Excel, formatting, and formulas, but by no means a master.

I have three sheets - `Summary` which is where the count value should be done, `Tracker` which is where the range to count is, and `OrigTrackerData` which has data used in the conditional formatting formula.

What I'm trying to do is count the number of cells within a certain table column that have a certain conditional formatting rule applied (rule below).

Here is the conditional formatting rule:

```
=A1<>VLOOKUP($A1,OrigTrackerData!$A:$L,COLUMN(),FALSE)
```

The intent of the rule, which is applied over the entirety of `Table710` which exists in `Tracker`, is to determine which cells have changed relative to `OrigTrackerData`, regardless of row order of the two sheets - column A of both sheets have an "index" of sorts.

I've gotten as far as something like `=COUNTIF(Table710[Notes], ???)` but I can't determine how to convert the conditional formatting formula to a `COUNTIF` condition.

I am open to accomplishing this via VBA as well - I originally attempted to do so using color functions found here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/colors.aspx but those functions apparently don't work on colors applied by conditional formatting.

Edit: BYate's comment neatly obviated the need for this. I am curious if something like this is possible though, but now just out of idle curiosity.

Comment: Do you need to count conditional formatting? Why not create a "helper column" that equates to `TRUE` or `FALSE` based on whether or not it meets the conditional formatting criteria, then count up the trues?

Comment: @BYates that's actually an incredibly obvious solution that I completely missed, I've already added it in and will probably stick with it. I am curious though if something like the original question is possible.

Comment: Maybe use [DisplayFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-displayformat-property-excel) property.